# How to integrate Resque plugin with rails 2.3.5 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to integrate my rails app with Resque plugin but in the doc it is not given that where should I write the code and how to use that code when running application. May be it is not understandable for me.

It would be helpful for me if any one explain it with an example application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add the gem in your config.gem 'resque'

After you can call by Resque.enqueue(xxx). All class call by Resque queue need to be load. You can add it on app/worker directory and add it in load_path. Or put in lib and use the autoloading stuff.

Comment: Thanks! For your reply.But could you please give me the detail or any URL for its tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the steps as specified in the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque).